# Slick 3.1.x Generic DAO for JdbcProfile error "value id is not a member of ..."

Tags: scala, slick, play-slick, genericdao

I'm trying to create a Slick 3.1.1 Generic DAO for my slick code-generated model. However, I'm facing one last compilation error that can't find how to fix.

The whole project is available in GitHub [play-authenticate-usage-scala](https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala) and the relevant source code is in the [GenericDao.scala](https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala/blob/master/app/dao/GenericDao.scala#L46).

The compiler error is the following:

```
[info] Compiling 16 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /home/bravegag/code/play-authenticate-usage-scala/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/bravegag/code/play-authenticate-usage-scala/app/dao/GenericDao.scala:46: value id is not a member of type parameter ET
[error]     def findById(id: PK): Future[Option[ER]] = db.run(tableQuery.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)
[error]                                                                           ^
```

Basically it doesn't recognize the `id` definition under the `Identifyable` trait. The top declarations are the following:

```
trait Identifyable[PK] extends Product {
  def id : PK
}

trait GenericDaoHelper {
  val profile: slick.driver.JdbcProfile
  import profile.api._

  class GenericDao[PK, ER <: Identifyable[PK], ET <: Table[ER], TQ <: TableQuery[ET]] @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
      (tableQuery: TQ) extends HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {
    import driver.api._

    /**
      * Returns the matching entity for the given id
      * @param id identifier
      * @return the matching entity for the given id
      */
    def findById(id: PK): Future[Option[ER]] = db.run(tableQuery.filter(_.id === id).result.headOption)
}
```

PS: note that I'm working with the latest Slick 3.1.1 this is critical because people have implemented similar solutions in the past but they change quite a bit from version to version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a previous Slick version [CrudComponent gist implementation](https://gist.github.com/lshoo/9785645) that can't be taken exactly as is but by adapting it to the latest Slick 3.1.x it then solves the `id` compilation issue described in the OP. The solution was basically a rearrangement of the template types and their bounds.

The final solution can be found in file [GenericDao.scala](https://github.com/bravegag/play-authenticate-usage-scala/blob/master/app/dao/generic/GenericDao.scala)

Comment: The second link ("final solution") is broken. Could you make it available on GitHub if you managed to clone it on time?

Comment: Hahah fixed it ... now works ... I refactored the generic part of the dao under generic that's all. In fact, you may copy paste the whole code under generic because should not have any other dependency

Comment: Thanks! that's why I decided to rewrite the usage example ... I settle for nothing but perfection :D you can also checkout the code under dao for sample extensions ... there I cover many Slick use-cases specially in the `UserDao` extension

Comment: This worked perfectly, except that the Entity and Identifyable traits must be applied to all tables auto-generated by the schema code generator, which is not ideal, so I preferred cluttering my own code with a `def getId(table: <Table>): Rep[Int] = table.id` everywhere. Also I could not replace the `PK` type `Long` to `Int` because of missing implicits (implicits are a real pain), so I made the type explicit. But you saved me from despair.

Comment: @JulienD in that project I customized the slick code gen to generate the needed extends etc. It is all automatic for me. Checkout the linked project under tests the Generator.scala file

Answer (score 2):

`ET` is a table (subtype of `Table[ER]`). From the error it is clear that `ET` does not have `Rep[PK]`

```
trait IdentifyableTable[PK] extends Table[ER] {
  def id: Rep[PK]
}
```

Instead of declaring `ET` as subtype of `Table[ER]`. Declare it as subtype of `IdentifyableTable[PK]`.

Declare your generic dao like this

```
class GenericDao[PK, ER <: Identifyable[PK], ET <: IdentifyableTable[PK], TQ <: TableQuery[ET]] ....
```

Comment: It is close but it doesn't really solve the problem ... for example User model is generated as `class User(_tableTag: Tag) extends Table[UserRow]` so `ET` is in this case `User`  and its id generated as `val id: Rep[Long]`

Comment: @GiovanniAzua You need to make `def id: Rep[PK]` available with the type `ET`. I don't think its generated dynamically